# dataframe is overwritten in subfunction

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scope

The following example shows an issue when a dataframe is edited in subfunction, but only parts of it are returned

Here is a breif explenation what the code does:

- `do_something()` creates `col3` and overwrites `col1` and `col2`
- `do_something()` returns only `col3`
- `df.merge(df_new, how='left')` adds `col3` to `df`
- `col1` and `col2` of `df` are changed in the subfunction and should no be changed in the main function

I dont understand this, since the variable changes within a function should not affect the values outside the function.

Your inputs on how to avoid this behaviour are highly appreciated.

```py
import pandas as pd

def do_something(df):
    df['col3'] = df['col1']+df['col2'] # new column
    df['col1'] = 111 #some change
    df['col2'] = 222 #some change
    return df[['col3']].copy()


data = {"col1":[1, 2, 3], "col2":[4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_new = do_something(df)
df.merge(df_new, how='left')


print('orginal df was modified by do_something')
print(df)

print('the return of the function do_something')
print(df_new)
```

Here you find the example online https://trinket.io/python3/3f273591fb

Current output of df

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   111   222     5
1   111   222     7
2   111   222     9
```

Expected output of df

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     5
1     2     5     7
2     3     6     9
```

## Answer

As refered in the comment of [Mustafa Aydın](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058284/dataframe-is-overwritten-in-subfunction#comment120291077_68058340) this is not a pandas issue, it's because of [mutability](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1/names1.html#1)

Comment: The merge line isn't currently doing anything because you've not assigned back `df = df.merge(df_new, how='left')`. Also you've passed a reference to `df` to the function. Which is why mutations affect it outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing a reference of the original object to the function so the orginal object gets edited.
You have to pass a copy to your function.

Use:

```
df_new = do_something(df.copy())
```

Comment: so the function input is not a copy, but more a pointer (as in C), which is strange to me since python does not have pointers

Comment: According to https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/#objects-in-python
everything assigned in Python is just a reference. Nevertheless i observed this specific behaviour only when working with pandas dataframes

Comment: me too, never had this issue before except with pandas

Comment: @endo.anaconda Nothing pandas-specific is going on here, it's because of mutability. Try `def f(x): x.append(3); return x.copy()` and then `a = []; f(a); f(a); print(a)`. Please see [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1/names1.html#1) for further.